# Advice on results for balls on regular $N$-dimensional grids

Tags: nt.number-theory, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, lattices, advice

I have obtained some results regarding balls on regular $N$-dimensional grids. I would like expert opinion on wether the results are significant or interesting enough for (trying to) publish them in a good Mathematics journal, say one indexed in JCR (not necessarily with a large impact factor).

Consider a regular grid in $N$ dimensions. The grid can be rather arbitrary, subject to some uniformity conditions (I can include details here if necessary). Some valid examples are the square or honeycomb grids ($N=2$), or a rectangular cuboid grid ($N=3$), as well as more complicated "grids" (or rather tessellations) like [this](https://robertlovespi.files.wordpress.com/2022/12/untitled.png) or [this](https://www.123rf.com/photo_156368106_bricks-that-form-a-diagonal-tessellation-on-the-ground-of-a-walkway-in-a-city.html).

My main results are:

1. An algorithm for computing the maximum (or minimum) number of grid points $n_\mathrm{max}$ (or $n_\mathrm{min}$) that can lie in the interior of a ball with radius $r$ given, when the center of the ball can be freeely chosen. The algorithm complexity is polynomial in $r$. However, the exponent grows quickly with $N$.
2. An algorithm for finding how $n_\mathrm{max}$ and $n_\mathrm{min}$ vary with the radius $r$, for $r$ in an interval $(0,R)$. In other words, the graphs of the functions $r \mapsto n_\mathrm{max}$ and $r \mapsto n_\mathrm{min}$ retricted to $(0,R)$ are obtained.

   Note that this does not immediately follow from item 1 above, as that only gives results for a fixed $r$, and "sampling" the interval $(0,R)$ to repeatedly apply 1 might result in variations of $n_\mathrm{max}$ or of $n_\mathrm{min}$ for intermediate values of $r$ being "missed".
3. Given $n$, the set (actually an interval) of radii $r$ such that there exists a ball of radius $r$ covering $n$ points is characterized. This is a generalization of the [Steinhaus circle problem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircleLatticePoints.html), which considers $N=2$, unit square grid, and radius $r$ such that the circle area is $n$. That is, we can now answer the question of how much we can alter $r$ from the value in Steinhaus problem and still have a circle that covers exactly $n$ points (for arbitrary $N$ and not necessarily square grids). The answer is only numerical: there is an algorithm to compute the interval of valid radii $r$, but no closed-form formula for the interval endpoints. The latter would probably be too much to ask for (I believe that currently only related asymptotic results are known).

In particular, the above allow exact computation of some sequences in OEIS (for example [A346993](https://oeis.org/A346993), [A123689](https://oeis.org/A123689), [A291259](https://oeis.org/A291259), [A125851](https://oeis.org/A125851), [A127406](https://oeis.org/A127406)), for which the currently known terms seem to have been obtained manually or conjectured from testing an arbitrary, "large" set of possible locations for the center.

Comment: sorry, what does 2 actually do? does it return the step function that $n_\cdot$ looks like when restricted to $(0,R)$?

Comment: @ZachHunter Yes, it is the function $r \mapsto n_\mathrm{max}$ retricted to $(0,R)$, and similarly for $n_\mathrm{min}$. I'll edit the text

Comment: It is hard to say anything concrete with what you have described so far. You essentially say you give (inefficiently) computable upper and lower on what I believe is typically known as the "Lattice point enumerator". Whether they are publishable depend almost entirely on how they compare to existing techniques. Searching on the quoted term may help you begin your comparison.

Comment: A good starting point for information (on related topics) in the lattice case is probably the bible: "Sphere packings, Lattices, and groups" by Conway-Sloane.